# Creating JSON data from Django model spanning foreign key

Tags: json, django

I'm using D3 within my Django 2 templates to create plots and I'm not sure how best to create a JSON object which contains data from both a parent and child model. For example, these are my models:

```
class Properties(models.Model):
  house_size     = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

class Prices(models.Model):
  price    = models.IntegerField(default=0)
  house    =models.ForeignKey(Properties,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=0)
```

I know that to create a JSON object from Prices I can do the following:

```
statdump = json.dumps(list(Prices.objects.all()), cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
```

However what if I want to create a JSON object containing price and house_size.

I can think of inefficient ways to solve this, for example iterating through the observations in the template and creating the JSON data there, but that doesn't seem very efficient. Is there a way that I could pass a JSON object from the view that contains house_size and price?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
from django.db.models import F
from django.core import serializers

objectQuerySet =  Prices.objects.all().annotate(house_size = F('house__house_size'))
statdump = serializers.serialize('json', objectQuerySet, fields=('price','house_size'))
```

[EDIT]
If you want to return it to a template try using this:

```
from django.db.models import F
from django.core import serializers
from django.http import JsonResponse

objectQuerySet =  Prices.objects.all().annotate(house_size = F('house__house_size')).values('price','house_size')
return JsonResponse({'jsonObject'=list(objectQuerySet)},safe=False)
```

Comment: This very nearly works, for example I can run:
    pricecomb = Prices.objects.all().annotate(house_size = F('house__house_size'))
    print(pricecomb.values('house_size','price'))  

and see that the result does indeed include the house_size field. However, when attempting to run json.dumps I then get an error that "Object of type 'Prices' is not JSON serializable". What else do I need to change here? 

I've also tried: 

    pricedump = serializers.serialize("json", pricecomb)

Which does work, however the house_size field is not present in the JSON object. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot that querysets cannot be serialised like that. You can try my edited answer if you just want to get a JSON object with house size and price.

Comment: Thanks again. Still having issues with this though. Your code does indeed create a correct queryset object. And I can see that if I print it out it looks as expected, i.e. it has price and house_size. I can also print the JSON object from within the view and it's still correct,  but when I use console.log within the template to write its contents out I see the foreign key and not the house size. Am I still missing something?

Comment: Try the code in the edit if you wanna return it to a template.